# Power Apps - Savedata error - Name may be too long

Tags: powerapps

hoping someone can help me out here.

Here is my code, very simple but produces an error.

I perform this test first:

```
Clear(Offline2);  
ClearCollect(Offline2, { Test: 2 })
```

I then have a vertical gallery which shows the results of this...

But when I press another button to save the data

```
SaveData(Offline2,"Offline2")
```

I get the error

> There was a problem saving your data. Name could be too long.

Has anyone experienced this before and is there a solution?

I am using an iPhone which has ample space on it.

I tried renaming the collection, etc.

Comment: Can you please share the Snapshot of the error and your gallery please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to setting and change your authoring version to 3.24024.12 this is the bug fix for this error. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem today. Solution was for us to go back to an older Power Apps Version for our App. Youn can change that under "Settings", then "Support" in your App. Maybe it helps!

[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2JIR.png)

Comment: Thanks Marcel, tried your suggestion, that was a no go. Need to figure this out as it's a important feature for my app. Thanks again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).